# Compute the output of the quantum teleportation circuit

Tags: quantum-state, teleportation

Sender and receiver use the teleportation protocol, where the sender teleports a quantum state $\left| \varphi \right>=\alpha\left| 0 \right> + \beta \left|1\right>$ to the receiver.

I want to implement this protocol, and then find the output $\left| ABC \right>$ of the quantum circuit when the measurement of the teleportation protocol in the left side is $\left| 11\right>$.

In other words: **when we measure $|11\rangle$, how to show that the state $|\varphi\rangle$ was really teleported?**

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? How far have you got? How are answers to previous, very similar questions not helping?

Comment: I am a little bit lost in your question. Could you please add results you have and how they differ from expectations?

Comment: This question was mentioned to me in the exam as I wrote above @MartinVesely

Answer (score 6):

Since your circuit is teleportation, $|C\rangle =|\varphi\rangle$ and since you measured $|11\rangle$ on $|AB\rangle$ the answer is $|ABC\rangle = |11\rangle|\varphi\rangle$.

**Now, let look why this is true.**

Firstly Hadamard and CNOT gate on second and third qubit prepares entangled Bell state $|\beta_{00}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$.

Now the circuit is in state

$$
|\varphi\rangle|\beta_{00}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle)(|00\rangle + |11\rangle) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[\alpha|0\rangle(|00\rangle + |11\rangle) + \beta|1\rangle(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)]
$$

Then you apply CNOT controlled by first qubit and targeting second qubit. This will negate second qubit in case the first qubit is in state $|1\rangle$. This means that only part $\beta|1\rangle(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$ is influenced.

Now, state of the circuit is changed to

$$
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[\alpha|0\rangle(|00\rangle + |11\rangle) + \beta|1\rangle(|10\rangle + |01\rangle)]
$$

Application of Hadamard gate on the first qubit change the state further to

$$
 \frac{1}{2}[\alpha(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)(|00\rangle + |11\rangle) + \beta(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)(|10\rangle + |01\rangle)]
$$

because $H|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$ and $H|1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)$.

Since you will measure first and second qubit, it is convenient to rearange the state to separate first two qubits. So, you can rewrite the state as

$$
\frac{1}{2} \big( |00\rangle(\alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle) 
+ |01\rangle (\alpha|1\rangle + \beta|0\rangle) 
+ |10\rangle (\alpha|0\rangle - \beta|1\rangle) 
+ |11\rangle (\alpha|1\rangle - \beta|0\rangle) \big)
$$

**In your case you measured $|11\rangle$ on first and second qubit. This means that the third qubit is in state**

$$
(\alpha|1\rangle - \beta|0\rangle)
$$

Since both first and second qubits are in state $|1\rangle$ both CNOT gates after measurement will be activated. The first one change the state of third qubit to

$$
(\alpha|0\rangle - \beta|1\rangle)
$$

Next two Hadamards together with CNOT implements controlled $Z$ gate which change a phase to oposite in case input qubit is in state $|1\rangle$. This leads to final state of third qubit

$$
(\alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle)
$$

**Hence, you can see that state from first qubit was teleported to third qubit.**

*Note: based on Nielsen and Chuang, pg. 27 and expanded*